# How to add all typography options with options tree in wordpress theme?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, fonts

I'm new to WordPress theme development, and I had to create a theme with options tree.

I have successfully add some options with options tree plugin in my wordpress theme. But I am really stand when I go to add typography option. I have complete section an settings on theme option with **'type' => 'typography'**, after that I see I have find some options on dashboards theme options like `'font-family'`, `'font-size'`, `'line-height'`, `'font-style'` etc. Now I want to query all methods but i have did not know how can I do this?

Please help me. 
Thanks for reading---

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using  optiontree typography option on the frontend.

```
$header_font = ot_get_option( 'heading_font' );
if(!empty($header_font)){
    $font = $header_font;
    $output .= 'h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3, h4, .h4, h5, .h5, h6, .h6, h1 a, .h1 a, h2 a, .h2 a, h3 a, .h3 a, h4 a, .h4 a, h5 a, .h5 a, h6 a, .h6 a{font-family: '.$font['font-family'].'; font-style: '.$font['font-style'].'; font-variant:'.$font['font-variant'].'; font-weight:'.$font['font-weight'].'; letter-spacing:'.$font['letter-spacing'].';  text-decoration:'.$font['text-decoration'].';    text-transform:'.$font['text-transform'].';  }';     
}
```